# Parent height over the child content CSS

Tags: css, vue.js

I've tried to fit the height of my parent class to child class without over height

this is my CSS file

**Parent**

```
&__video
  position: relative
  width: 471px
  background: red
  border-radius: 12px
  @include box-05
```

**Child**

```
.player
  position: relative
  width: var(--width)
```

and this is how I call on HTML

```
VideoEmbed.video-introduction__video(
  source-url="*****"
)
```

by the way `VideoEmbed` is a component which contain this child styling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by the way, I solve it with add `display: flex` but I not sure it is the right way to solve it

```
&__video
  display: flex
  position: relative
  width: 471px
  background: red
  border-radius: 12px
  @include box-05
```